# Get num_row once for different values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm very new to PHP, I'm trying to get result from database of rows count. I have used below given method:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM donors WHERE blood_group = 'A+'");
$Apositive = $result->num_rows;
```

Now as you can see I have to execute this query for every blood group.

Is there any easier method to get all these results in one way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT blood_group, count(*) AS donor_count
  FROM donors
 GROUP BY blood_group
```

will return a series of results, one for each `blood_group`, with a count of the donors for that group in `donor_count`; and you can then just loop over the resultset

**EDIT**

```
$query = "SELECT blood_group, count(*) AS donor_count
      FROM donors
     GROUP BY blood_group";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf (
            "Blood Group: %s has %d donors)\n", 
            $row["blood_group"], 
            $row["donor_count"]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the best solution.. i tried it and it returned this array `mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 2
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 10
    [type] => 0
)` what should i do next ?

Comment: You need to loop over the resultset, fetching each result in turn.... pretty basic PHP 101 - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Great!! it printed out all stored blood group in database `(A+) (A-) (AB+) (AB-) (B+) (B-) (O+) (O-)` but can't figure how to get rows count .. I have tried `printf ("%i (%s)\n", $row->num_rows, $row["blood_group"]);` but no luck it just print what i mentioned

Comment: So how did you get it printing out the groups? You iterated over the resultset fetching each result in turn and displaying `blood_group`..... modify your display so that you display `donor_count` as well

Comment: Awww i was trying this way `$row["blood_group"], donor_count` but now i got it very clear. Thank you so much !!